# Internet Explorer "There was a problem sending the command to the program" error

Tags: internet, connection, fios

When I click on links to other URLs on web pages or in email messages, this error occurs about 90% of the time.  Began occurring when I switched from a cable service to Verizon FIOS. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Very strange! Have you installed any Verizon software? Have you tried to use another browser (Firefox, Opera, Safari...)?

Answer (score 0):

In the bad old days, ISP's provided CD's that you installed on your PC, these often provided custom versions of IE or added their own toolbars and other clutter. Perhaps Verizon still have this regrettable habit.

> Click Start, and then type Internet Explorer in the Start Search box.
>   Click Internet Explorer (No Add-On). Internet Explorer opens without add-ons, toolbars, or plug-ins.
>   Test Internet Explorer to verify that it works correctly.
>
> If the issue gets resolved use the below mentioned links for further resolution –
>   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Internet-Explorer-add-ons-frequently-asked-questions
>   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-the-Internet-Explorer-Add-on-Manager

From http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/error-message-there-was-a-problem-sending-the/b259299f-223a-4a1f-85c6-20bf6b1ea82b

In IE you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the menu-bar, choose "Manage Add-Ons", then disable anything associated with Verizon. At the very least, you can use this method to find out if your problem is caused by an Add-on.

Comment: I had disabled all the add-ons previously, so when I went to the search suggestion, two IEs were listed; one just Internet Explorer and the other Internet Explorer (64 bit). Are there any "plug-ins" that do not show up in the display at Control Panel/Internet Options/Programs?